# Recent average, without full logging of all data

Tags: php, performance, language-agnostic

This is mainly a performance issue. It is to help get the current average of the past N (30?) values. The context here would be to monitor the average execution time for the past N data requests in a server. While the obvious solution, is to log the all past N requests, in which all N request is read, and tabulated. Creating a performance hit relative to the data request in question.

As this is mainly use as a means of measure and not a perfect running estimate, the question? To solve this problem in the most effective manner.

While the solution may be language neutral, I would be implementing in php :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of saving the last N values, organize your values in "buckets" with a predefined bucket-size, and for each bucket, only save the sum of all values in the bucket.

Whenever a bucket is full, you can delete the oldest bucket. (The best way to do this would be a ring buffer)

This allows you to cut your memory usage by a factor of BUCKET_SIZE, but obviously your average is not over the last N values anymore, but over the last N to N + BUCKET_SIZE.

Comment: So the avg will be based on the recent bucket... Though a slight delay is present, (for data to fill a bucket) it is certainly a much smaller footprint :)

Comment: no, the avg will be based on the avg over all buckets, including the "half-full" one - just calculate the sum over all buckets and divide by `(BUCKET_SIZE * NUMBER_OF_FULL_BUCKETS) + NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_IN_HALF_FULL_BUCKET`. 

That way, you don't even have any delay, however, there might be a slight "jump" in you value whenever a bucket is full and the oldest one is replaced by a new empty one.